# FindNReplace VBA not working properly with numbers

Tags: excel, vba

everyone!

I'm trying to use a VBA code I found online to transform a scale from 2 to 12 to 0 to 10.
The thing is, the code works almost perfectly, except for "12", which it replaces with "8" instead of "10". Actually, sometimes it works fine, sometimes it doesn't, and I don't know why. Any help would be really appreciated!

Here's what I'm trying to replace and the code:

| REPLACEMENT | INPUT |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 6 | 4 |
| 7 | 5 |
| 8 | 6 |
| 9 | 7 |
| 10 | 8 |
| 11 | 9 |
| 12 | 10 |

CODE:

```
Sub MultiFindNReplace()

'Update 20140722

Dim Rng As Range

Dim InputRng As Range, ReplaceRng As Range


xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"

Set InputRng = Application.Selection

Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Original Range ", xTitleId, InputRng.Address, Type:=8)

Set ReplaceRng = Application.InputBox("Replace Range :", xTitleId, Type:=8)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each Rng In ReplaceRng.Columns(1).Cells


InputRng.Replace what:=Rng.Value, replacement:=Rng.Offset(0, 1).Value

Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Are the cells all of the same number format?

Comment: Yes! I've tried both with "General" format and "Number" format for both parts (Original values and replacement values)

Comment: Specify the `LookAt` (3rd) parameter.

Comment: May be a very newbie question, but do you mean the line "InputRng.Replace what:=Rng.Value, replacement:=Rng.Offset(0, 1).Value"? Wouldn't I have to specify it for each new sheet/workbook? I was hoping to keep the code universal, so anyone I pass it can use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that the 2 in 12 is being replaced by 0 making it 10, subsequently 10 is being replaced by 8.

To fix this simply add `LookAt:=xlWhole`.

```vb
InputRng.Replace What:=Rng.Value, Replacement:=Rng.Offset(0, 1).Value, LookAt:=xlWhole
```

P.S. For this specific find/replace could you not simply subtract 2?

Comment: This worked, and I understood quite well what the problem was! I don't think simply subtracting 2 would work because I have ~19k lines, with each one of them being an answer around this range. I'm afraid if I did that it would mess up with the answers. But thanks a lot, problem solved! :D

Comment: @NINHA.X FYI Remarks section in the [docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.replace). The settings for LookAt, SearchOrder, MatchCase, and MatchByte are saved each time you use this method. If you don't specify values for these arguments the next time you call the method, the saved values are used. Setting these arguments changes the settings in the Find dialog box, and changing the settings in the Find dialog box changes the saved values that are used if you omit the arguments. To avoid problems, set these arguments explicitly each time that you use this method.